# Should I apply for a lecturer position in mathematics or physics if I have a degree in maths and PhD in physics?

Tags: career-path, changing-fields

I am finishing my Ph. D. in physics and I have a degree in mathematics. Currently, I am planning to apply for a lecturer position in Australia. Will it be more feasible to apply for a lecturer position in mathematics or in physics?

Update: Thank you all for your advice. Currently, my papers are still under review. I think I shall try applying for the positions in both subjects.

Comment: Since the word "lecturer" can mean different things in different systems, is an Australian "lecturer" the same as a UK "lecturer", which would be equivalent to a US "assistant professor"?

Comment: Also, what is your publication record?

Comment: Read the announcements of the available positions.  They will contain the required qualifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for any position for which you are qualified. Read the person specification for the advertised post. Usually it specifies which degrees are required and which area of PhD  the candidate should have. If your profile fits the description go for it and apply. You can apply for as many positions as you like.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Physics will be more likely as that is the more recent and the higher degree.  In particular, this would be the case for more top tier research positions.

All that said, you should (a) blanket the waterfront and apply in both areas--jobs in academia are scarce and (b) look for positions where your particular blend of knowledge is most wanted (e.g. I dated a lady who was a professor in comp sci, but really had a math background and teaching load...but close enough to CS so she fit there).